# Ordering slightly shuffled list by order of most frequent occurrence

Tags: sorting

Let's say you have a list of items that are in "slight disarray". In his example, Blue is *mostly* on top, Red is *mostly* in the middle and Green is *mostly* in the bottom.

```
Blue
Blue
Blue
Red
Blue
Green
Red
Red
Red
Blue
Green
Green
Green
Blue
```

Is there an algorithm that goes: Well, most of the Blue are in the beginning, so we'll put them first. Most of the Red are in the middle, so they come next, and so on, producing the following output:

```
Blue
Blue
Blue
Blue
Blue
Blue
Red
Red
Red
Red
Green
Green
Green
Green
```

Or simply just:

```
Blue
Red
Green
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of an existing algorithm, but to figure out the order of elements, you could count the number of times an element of X comes before an element of Y and vice versa. If X comes before Y more than Y comes before X, then order X first (for all X/Y pairs). It's pretty inefficient (polynomial time) but that might be a good start to making a better algorithm.

---

For example in the following list . . .

```
Red
Red
Blue
```

. . . each Red comes before a Blue (two total) and Blue does not come before any reds (zero total) so order Reds first.

There will be times where there is no precedence such as the following list . . .

```
Red
Blue
Blue
Red
```

. . . Since red comes before two blues (two total) and each blue comes before a red (two total) then there wouldn't be a precedence  with this algorithm.

---

To make it a bit more efficient and might fit your model better, preprocess the list to collapse consecutive elements with their counts. For example the following list

```
Red
Red
Red
Red
Red
Blue
Blue
Red
```

Could be represented as

```
Red (5)
Blue (2)
Red (1)
```

And now you can multiply your calculations by the count of elements. In the above, 5 reds come before 2 blues so there are 10 reds coming before blues. Similarly 2 blues come before 1 red so there are 2 blues comes before red. So we will order Reds first.

---

This same idea came be extended to include more than two distinct elements.

Answer (score -1):

Try quick sorting:

```
public class Quick
{
    private static int partition(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi)
    {
        int i = lo, j = hi+1;
        while (true)
        {
        while (less(a[++i], a[lo])) if (i == hi) break;
        while (less(a[lo], a[--j])) if (j == lo) break;
        if (i >= j) break;
        exch(a, i, j);
        }
    exch(a, lo, j);
    return j;
    }
    private static void sort(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi)
    {
        if (hi <= lo) return;
        int j = partition(a, lo, hi);
        sort(a, lo, j-1);
        sort(a, j+1, hi);
    }
}
```

Source: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/Quick.java

Comment: This is a standard Quick Sort? Then I think you misunderstood my question. I've tried to rephrase it to make it more clear what I'm after.